# Objective-C: CoreData Getting related Entity in one-to-many

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

IN a bit of a pickle. I am implementing a CoreData solution and I have two entities, Site and Post. Now Site has many Posts as Post belongs to one Site, as reflected in the model diagram.

In my entity code I have :

## Site.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* post;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* tag;
   ...
@interface Site (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
 - (void)addPostObject:(Post *)value;
 - (void)removePostObject:(Post *)value;
 - (void)addPost:(NSSet *)value;
 - (void)removePost:(NSSet *)value;
```

## Post.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * views;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* comment;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Site * site;
...
@interface Post (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
 - (void)addCommentObject:(Comment *)value;
 - (void)removeCommentObject:(Comment *)value;
 - (void)addComment:(NSSet *)value;
 - (void)removeComment:(NSSet *)value;

 - (void)addMediaObject:(Media *)value;
 - (void)removeMediaObject:(Media *)value;
 - (void)addMedia:(NSSet *)value;
 - (void)removeMedia:(NSSet *)value;
@end
```

My issue is, i need to access a post that belongs to a Site, so i guess I logically need to get an array of all the posts belonging to a user. can someone provide me sample code to do this? Ive been scouring the internet to find sample code but yeah, no luck so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you associating a user with a post in the first place? I don't see any attribute or relationship in your posted code that associates a user... but, for the sake of argument, let's assume that a Post entity has an attribute named user (for this simple example, user is just an NSString that identifies the user by name).

```
NSString* user = @"our_username";
NSFetchRequest* request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.user LIKE[cd] %@", user];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:someContext]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* postsForUser = [someContext executeRequest:request error:&error];
if( !postsForUser ) {
  // handle error
}

// Will contain all posts by user
NSLog(@"posts: %@", postsForUser);
```

Comment: hey mate, well cant you see in @Post.h I have a Site * site; attribute and in Site an NSSet. Thats whats needed right?

Comment: sorry mate, i meant Site and Post, forget User. User doesnt exist.

Comment: So maybe I am confused then. You just want to get an array of posts belonging to a site? You already have that on your Site object...

Comment: Hi Jason. Thats right, array of posts belonging to site. I am not sure how I already have that. NSSet *post? Is that an array?

Comment: Yes, those are all your posts. Usually you would name the relationship plural, but it isn't required. If you iterate that set, it will contain all the posts for that specific site.